# Unable to connect to samba shared folder via windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking, samba, file-sharing

im new to linux and Samba.

### **Aim**

Create a called Shared_folder which can be accessed by ALL users (group name = users). Therefore, in order to map the drive in windows, the user is promoted to enter valid user credentials.

### **Issue**

I have the following Shared_folder with the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody users 4096 Dec 27 00:24 Shared_folder
```

..and the following Samba config:

```
[Shared_folder]
    printable = no
    writeable = yes
    path = /home/Shared_folder
    force group = users
    comment = Common Documenets accessible by all users
    valid users = @users
    create mode = 757
    public = no
    directory mode = 777
```

But it when I try to map the drive in windows im unable to pass the user validation part as it keeps failing.

Could someone please shed some light as to how to get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i hope you have restarted samba server after modifying smb config

Comment: which OS you are installing samba server

Comment: Using Turnkey Linux File Server (http://www.turnkeylinux.org/fileserver) which is running on Debian 6.0.5 (Squeeze). Also I have reestarted the samba server a every time i have made a change

Comment: can u attache samba log (/var/log/samba/log.smbd)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SELinux you need to run this command as root:

```
chcon -t samba_share_t /home/Shared_folder
```

Comment: Im getting the following:
 
**chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/home/Shared_folder'**

Also what does this do? and what is samba_share_t?

Comment: this did it for me. thanks. using stat [dir path], you should be able to see the current context and compare it with a working directory

Answer (score 1):

if you got error  **chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/home/Shared_folder'**, using full label for directory. because this directory dosen`t have any label, so it cant get a partial label.(you can see current label with ls -Z).
use below command to set full label for it:

```
chcon -h system_u:object_r:samba_share_t /home/Shared_folder
chcon -R -h system_u:object_r:samba_share_t /home/Shared_folder*
```

Answer (score 0):

few things that might cause to occur you problem

1. samba server not starting because following error

Log file /var/log/samba/log.smbd

```
 smbd/server.c:501(smbd_open_one_socket) smbd_open_once_socket: open_socket_in: Address already in use
```

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=726936

```
sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only=1
```

2. samba password for the user not configured

smbpasswd -a username

Comment: I added the logs above as requested. If there are still no obvious reasons why this should occur, could you please provide steps to create a Shared_folder which can be accessed by ALL users (group name = users).